# Orthogonality : Is it axiom?

Tags: orthogonality

me basically without any doubt use tuples to represent orthogonal elements in a vector format such as:

(x,y) represent x,y coordinates. (as we learn in highschool).

but still I confuse how could we understand orthogonality and what kind of assumption or axioms lie behind of this (x,y) representation (or for the higher dimension)

more elaborately, is there any mathematical contradiction or paradox if I just say

"oh, here I can show you there exists two different elements which could be classified as orthogonal, which I mean, they are independent. You can believe me. It's mathematically well-defined."

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Perhaps this is because of confused terminology. In standard terminology orthogonality and independence are different (orthogonality means that the angle is right while independence in two dimension means that they are at least not parallell). Paradox means a statement that contradicts it self - a statement can be plain false without being a paradox. Update your question, either by using standard terminology or add definitions to your terms if you don't want to use standard terminology.

Comment: Thx for your valuable comment. how to define paralle(ness) in algebraic sense out of the geometric manner?

Comment: Orthogonality is defined when you are given an inner product. And in the Euclidean space, Pythagorean theorem essentially tells that there is a natural inner product on the Cartesian coordinates, from which the concept of orthogonality follows. Of course, it coincides with the perpendicularity in Euclidean space under suitable interpretation.

Comment: @skyking for update I need one more question to be answered. As you had already mentioned, independence and orthognality is different, however, in cartesian coordinates, (x,y), they are graphically represented in orthogonal manner and also they are called independent two axes, what is the relationship between orthogonality and independence in the context of cartesian corrdinates?

Comment: Also note that given any vector, the existence of a (non-zero) vector which is orthogonal to it can be proven in several ways, depending on how exactly you've defined your plane. That means that in order to get a concrete answer, you need to be clear: What exactly is your definition of this collection of vectors we call "the plane"?

Comment: @Arthur thx for critical question. Actually I don't know what plane is. What is the plane? I could imagine of two "independent(algebraic sense)" vectors which holds a power to "span".. but still it's vague. What I only know about plane is that we have two vectors, x,y and ax+by =0 (a,b scalar), if  a=b=0  always, collection of this vector could be understood as a plane I think.

Answer (score 1):

A coordinate system doesn't **have to** be orthonormal or even orthogonal, but it is very common that one choses such a coordinate system because that simplifies the situation. Orthonormal coordinate system is also called cartesian cordinate system.

Because of this simplification one might opt for assuming that coordinate systems are orthonormal by default as it's normally not a problem in chosing such a coordinate system. This might be what is assumed in (your) high school.

Without this assumption you cannot make much out of orthogonality just by looking at the tuples, but if you can assume that it's cartesian coordinates you could.